# python machine learning evaluation metric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I apply SVM(rbf) model on a pandas dataframe which has 8528 rows (8528 samples) and it classify 4 classes. train-test split is 50-50. at the end I get this results :

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       A       0.00      0.00      0.00       386
       N       0.60      1.00      0.75      2563
       O       0.00      0.00      0.00      1180
       ~       0.00      0.00      0.00       135

accuracy                           0.60      4264
```

does anybody knows why the scores of other classes except 'N' are equal to 0.00? (it has approximately same results for evey runnig, even for diffrent train-test split percentage for example 80-20 or 70-30)

Comment: There could be several reasons why the model is not performing well for the class N. One possible reason could be imbalanced dataset, where some classes have fewer samples than others. Another reason could be that the features used to train the model are not informative enough. could also be that the hyperparameters of the SVM model need to be tuned to improve its performance. start by analyzing the dataset and the features used to train the model, and try different hyperparam for the SVM model. You can consider different classification algorithms.

Comment: thanks in advance. you are right. the dataset is somehow imbalance , infact the distribution is like this: N :5154  A:771   O:2557 ~:46  Total:8528 , maybe I should try some other techniques like "SMOTE" in order to balance my dataset.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of overfitting: Your model always returns the class "N".

When you consider this these numbers make sense, e.g.:

```
Precision(N) = # (Rightly classified as N) /  # (Everything classified as N) = 0.6
Recall(N) = # (Rightly classified as N) / # (Every element in N) = 1
```

This is probably the case, because your dataset is very unbalanced: About 60% of your data is "N".

Comment: No, its not overfitting, as there is not enough information in the question to determine that.

Comment: the distribution of dataset is like this: N :5154      A:771     O:2557     ~:46    TOTAL:8528

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Maybe I am misunderstanding something about the question then? Please help me if I do, here is my thinking: 
If the Recall is 0 for a class that means none of the data in that class is classified correctly. On the other hand the recall for class N is 1, so every data of class N is classified correctly. 
The precision of N is 0.6, so some other data is also classified as N. Also 2563 / 4264 = (number of samples for N / all samples) = 0.6, so the numbers match with my thesis that the model is just returning the class "N" for everything. And that would be overfitting, right?